# Transfer drag event - Jquery / UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Ive got a problem here.

I want to make elements transfer their dragged event.

This means, I want to start dragging one element - and if this element reaches a point ( for example, left: 300 ) I want to hide the first element. Then I want to add a second element to the same drag event, for example an other div. So the drag will look like a single drag for the user but change its elements.

This should happen in one drag.

Anyone knows how I can make this?

Comment: Sounds like something that is going to be really complicated

Comment: actually, I got an approach: maybe use the other element as a helper, then somehow check on the condition (left: 300) for example
    $().draggable({ helper :  someotherelement });

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to use the drag event documented here:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

in the drag event check the left and top values and change the HTML of your helper element based on the left and top values of your drag event.

HTH